# FlickrJ-Android Alway authentication failed

Tags: android, flickr

I am developing a small android application to upload photo to Flickr. I use Flickj-android library to call Flickr API. But I can't authorize my app. I always get:

[image: Webpage not avaiable]

I refer to this example: https://github.com/luminousman/Flickr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe url without "m" more correct?

I'm current use this url: https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxx-yyyy.

Try use [scribejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) library for auth/requests.